# New Image in Resources Files is not Appearing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm facing a problem that drives me crazy.

1) I had put an image into Resources-Files (RESX) using Project->Properties->Resources. I set a button with that image normally.

2) In the code due to some reasons, I load the image into an image-type variable and change its colors (the image is a PNG to appear like icon-button). During the execution, if user change icons colors, I change the image-variable to that new color and reload the button image with this image-variable. Everything goes ok. See:

```
 dim MyButton1_Image as Image = nothing
```

in another local I set:

```
 MyButton1_Image = My.Resources.ImageOfButton1
```

during the code execution, I set:

```
 ChangeColor(MyButton1_Image)   << user had changed the icons colors
 MyButton1.BackgroundImage = MyButton1_Image
```

**Everything is functioning fine. I have more than 35 icons/buttons doing this.**

**Only this specific image is the problem - and I changed the image file (file and filename) and the variable name.**

3) Yesterday I changed one of the images, keeping its name. The button immediately changed its backgroundimage to the new design.

BUT,
when the code runs and I load again the image file into the variable and re-load the image-variable into button backgroundimage, the image that appears is the older one.

Weird, since I see the new image in the button when I open the form in Design mode! And if I open the PROJECT-PROPERTIES-RESOURCES I see also the new designed image.

I guessed: ok, probably the RESOURCE file (RESX) did not update itself. So, I went to RESOURCE properties from PROJECT PROPERTIES and "RUN CUSTOM TOOL". The problem persists.

Ok, so I

1- copied the image to ANOTHER NAME,

2- added it into Resources,

3- changed the image in the button imagebackground property (the image appears ok),

4- change the code to reflect the new image, like:

```
       MyButton1_Image = My.Settings.NewerImage
       MyButton1.BackgroundImage = MyButton1_Image
```

Wow... The image that appears is still the older one...

Yes, I could re-create a new button with a new image file and so forth.
But, what is really happening here?

Why Visual Studio shows me the correct image in RESOURCES and in the button on the FORM (Design mode) but when I call it at runtime the image is the older one?

I'm not using the RESOURCES folder and I won't want to do this.

Thanks for any help.

**Update**

To all folks trying to help me:
1- The old image does not exist anyway! It is not in any folder, neither pointed by Resources.Resx/Design nor visualized in Project/Properties/Resources.

2- I set the correct image manually (Design mode) perfectly. But, the same image with the same name (Resources.Imagem1) if loaded in runtime causes the old one to appear.

3- The older image was there yesterday! I changed it and, after these occurencies, I deleted it! Not satisfied, I changed the FILE and its FILENAME - the button loads ANOTHER FILE AND FILENAME.  But, unfortunetly, I have the SAME behavior!

4- It seems like RESOURCE.RESX had written the image within it and is not getting change it anymore. But, with different FILENAME, how could it be possible?

Comment: Did you try to clean and rebuild your project?

Comment: Also, go into your solution folder structure and look for that image (old).

Comment: @DiscipleMichael, yes, I tried to clean and rebuild. I also clean OBJ folder manually and entirely and recompiled - none. I also reviewed entirely the RESOURCES.DESIGN and all references are OK (to the new image).

Comment: Yes, I see the new image in images folder and RESOURCES shows me the correct image. And I tried to create a new button and set the new image in its PROPERTIES and everything was OK.  But, when I load the image from My.Resources, the older one appears  :(.

Comment: hmmm.. you're at one of those fun crossroads where you have to decide to do a fix and move on, or spend more time finding out why it broke.  Either way has pros/cons.  Either way is fine.

Comment: @DiscipleMichael, yes, I agree with you. The problem is that I HAD DONE IT. I created a new image and set the new image following the above and, during the runtime, the old image appears - it seems like a reference inside RESOURCES.RESX or it is not compiling, neither by VS nor by CUSTOM TOOL.  It´s amazing!

Comment: Are you expecting something loaded from resources then changed (`ChangeColor()`) to persist?

Comment: @Plutonix, I'm sorry, your comment is not clear to me...  See: I load the image from Resources in Button Properties at Design Time 100%, no problem at all. But, using "Button.BackgroundImage = My.Resource.<SameImage>" the OLD image appears! And it does not exist in ANY folder of project! And I opened Resources.Resx and check it to see if pointing to wrong place, and not, everything is ok. And if I see the image in Project/Properties/Resources, the image is 100%. The old one simply does not exist anymore (it was deleted yesterday!). Tks!